# jQuery: apply function to elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `jQuery.each()`, I can *iterate* through members of the array:

```
// This is NOT what I am looking for.
$('.example a').each(function() {
    // do a lot of things here
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

However, I need to apply a function to the jQuery array itself, and not to its members. So I wrote a little plugin to do this:

```
$.fn.all = function( callback ) { return callback.call( this ); }

$('.example a').all(function() {
    // do a lot of things here
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Please notice that in the function above, `this` will be set to the collection of the elements - which is what I require.
Now I'm sure that jQuery should have an elegant way to do this, but I haven't found anything in the documentation, or by Googling.

**Is it possible, and if it is, how do I achieve this without using custom plugins?**

**UPDATE:** I can not do `$('.example a').css('color', 'red');` directly. I have a dozens of calculations in the function, so I have to use something similar to the plugin I wrote.
**I am asking for a callback. The correct answer must provide a callback similar to the custom function.**

Comment: What does "apply a function to the jQuery array itself" mean, exactly?

Comment: @Oriol He probably meant as a whole and not one by one.

Comment: .each applies a callback to each member of the array through iteration, so "this" will be the members of that array.
What I need is that "this" will be the array itself, not its members. Please read the updated question.

Comment: _"The correct answer must provide a callback similar to the custom function"_ Do you mean 1) a callback when all functions have completed; 2) 2)  callback when each of the the functions have completed; or 3) both 1) and 2)?

Comment: No, maybe using the word 'callback' is not quite right. I need to apply the function to the array, and the `this` variable inside the function's scope should be referenced to the jQuery array. Please see my own custom function to understand what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a plugin, you can use `call` directly:

```
(function() {
  // do a lot of things here
  this.css('color', 'red');
}).call($('.example a'));
```

Or consider passing the array-like object as an argument

```
(function(arrayLike) {
  // do a lot of things here
  arrayLike.css('color', 'red');
})($('.example a'));
```

Or if you prefer a jQuery way

```
$.each([$('.example a')], function(){
  // do a lot of things here
  this.css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way to this, and I upvote it. However, I pretty much rather that I use the `$(...).something` format, because of the way it is currently formatted.

Comment: Then adding the method to `$.fn` seems the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't

```
$('.example a').css('color', 'red');
```

be enough?

Comment: It should, other than that I have more than a .css() in there, and all of them needs to be a) in a function b) done at the same time

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft, It is not possible in JS to execute more than one command/function at a time; so ... what?

Comment: I think I'm a bit unclear. As I said, I want to execute the action to the array itself, not to execute the action to all of its members at once. jQuery by itself allows a certain action to be done on the selected elements, for example `$('a').hide()` does have exactly the same results as `$('a').each(function() { $(this).hide() })`, however the latter would be slower. But as you can see, `.hide()` is done to all of the links at once, instead of iterating through the members and doing the action one-by-one. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft Wouldn't `$('a').hide()` be implicitly doing an `each`?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio I've tried it many times, and it seems that either it does not do an `each`, or it does it so much better than passing a callback function to do it foreach element. Either way, I need the better performance here.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the straight-forward (jQuery-esque) way to do what you want:

```
var $collection = $('.example a');
$collection.each(function() {
    // do a lot of things here
    $collection.css('color', 'red');
});
```

//And another reason I dislike jQuery's implementation of `each()`. 
//but most of all, wrong argument-order and the abuse of `this` to pass the current value/node

Here my prefered implementation. Mostly like `Array.prototype.forEach()`, and the nice parts of `$.each()`.

```
$.fn.forEach = function(fn, scope){
    if(scope != null) fn = fn.bind(scope);
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i)
        if(false === fn(this[i], i, this)) break;
    return this;
}
```

and your code would be like:

```
$('.example a').forEach(function(node, index, $collection){
    //and don't use `$(this)`, since `this` most of the time references `window`
    //unless you've bound the function to a scope, or passed one to forEach

    var $node = $(node);

    $collection.css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: While still using a custom `$.fn` method, this is by far the best and most-detailed forEach implementation I have ever seen. Also, +1 for the "*`this` abuse*" part, can't express how much I agree!

Answer (score 0):

this

```
$('.example a')
```

returns collection of matched elements. And this

```
$('.example a').css('color', 'red');
```

sets color red to all elements in the collection.

That's how jQuery works.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I don't just do a .css() in there. Please read the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible getting all the calculations at the same time, you should use threads for that, or a `webWorker`. You can get more info about this in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Thank you, but actually I need the callback to be linear instead. Your answer does not solve my problem, but it is a great article to read nonetheless.

Comment: I don't use foreach because it applies the function "for each" element. e.g: `$els[0].doFunc(); $els[1].doFunc();  $els[2].doFunc();  ... `
But I require that the function be applied to all of the elements at the same time: `$els.doFunc();`

Answer (score 0):

You can cache selector, utilize [`$.queue()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/)

```js
var elems = $(".example a");
$.queue(elems, "q", function() {
  $(this).css("color", "red");
  console.log(this)
});
$.dequeue(elems, "q")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="example">
  <a href="#">a</a>
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <a href="#">c</a>
</div>
```

Comment: While not directly what I asked for, this is a pretty useful way to define queues, and I'm glad I learned it today. Thank you!

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft _"While not directly what I asked for"_ Why included comments referencing `$.when()`, `.then()`. Was not certain what _"I have a dozens of calculations in the function"_ was?

Comment: But this is using map, which iterates over the elements as a foreach, so you are not dealing with the array, only with the elements inside. Or am I wrong?(which s very possible)

Comment: This is the closest thing to a native jQuery method (which I asked for), however using queues are not necessarily required (which I didn't ask for), hence the sentence. I'm grateful nonetheless, as I am already using the example you provided in other parts of my code. Thanks again, and sorry if I were somewhat unclear with my question, but learning jQuery queues certainly makes life easier.